# Finding optimal threshold in extreme value theory - Peak Over Threshold-method (POT)

Tags: r, cross-validation

I am using r and doing a project with extreme values. Now I need to find optimal threshold based on charts outputs but I can't find any information how to interprete them. I am using `ismev` package:

```
u1=quantile(rainData,0.85)
u2=quantile(rainData,0.95)
ismev::gpd.fitrange(rainData, u1, u2)
```

[image]

```
ismev::mrl.plot(rainData)
```

[image]

How can I "read" optimal threshold from these two charts? What should I look at? It doesn't have to be the EXACT best thereshold.

Comment: The tag extreme learning machine seems to refers to some very specific machine learning process. For extreme value theory, you should get better answers on cross validated (or even the quant finance SE).

Comment: edited, added cross validation, hope someone will help:)